# Is it possible to run setInterval in background in expo react native?

Tags: react-native, scheduled-tasks

I am a newbie to React Native and develop my first apps

Here is My app feature:
Check the current location each 10 sec and send the location information to database.

I am using setinterval
But finally, I found that the apps can't run in the background. When the user minimizes the app or turns off the screen or opens another app, the app does not run.

My code

```
const TASK_NAME = 'MY_TASK';
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_NAME, () => {
  try {
   this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("AAAAA");
       }, 1000);

    return this.timer;
  } catch (error) {
    return BackgroundFetch.Result.Failed;
  }
  });

  const register=()=> {
   
  return BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(TASK_NAME, {
    minimumInterval: 2, // seconds
    stopOnTerminate: false, // android only,
    startOnBoot: true, // android only
  });
}

const unregister=()=> {
  return BackgroundFetch.unregisterTaskAsync(TASK_NAME);
}

export default{
  register,
  unregister,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of react native, there's nothing that they give . you have 2 ways

1. create your own native custom module and then use it
2. Use this [rn-background-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer) for the same purpose.

Comment: Doesn't work on expo. You need to eject expo first